# Issue with accessing params/queryParams inside transition.to/from in Ember 3.8 after adding "transition-state" deprecation

Tags: ember.js

As part of upgrading our project's Ember version from 3.8 to 3.12, we have introduced deprecation id - "transition-state" as a part of deprecation workflow. With this deprecation, it is not possible to access state, params or queryParams directly from the Transition object so we decided to access that using transition.to. But there are some instances where even transition.to is not having the required params even though it used to have the same when accessed directly (before introducing the deprecation)

On exploring transition object, we found that an attribute which seems like some internal API key (starts with something like **PARAMS**-26198*********-****) has the required params object that was desired. Although it doesn't seem like an ideal solution, I would like to know if there are better ways to access the params or queryParams from transition object

Comment: Hello!! can you add some example code? what situations don't have queryParams?